# Unserialize() return empty object

Tags: php, oop, serialization

I serialized object, but after deserialization object is empty and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

This is my code:

```
class Foo implements \Serializable {

    public $default = 10;
    public $setMe;
    public $removeOnSerialize = 'blah';

    public function serialize()
    {
        unset($this->removeOnSerialze);
        return serialize($this);
    }

    public function unserialzie($serialized)
    {
        $unserialized = unserialize();
        $unserialize->removeOnSerialize = 'Set some value';
        return $unserialized;
    }

}

$obj = new Foo();
$obj->setMe = 9999;

print_r($obj) // here I have all as exepcted

$serialized = serialize($obj);

$unserialized = unserialize($serialized);

print_r($unserialized); 

//object properties after deserialization
$unserialized->default === 10 // correct
$unserialized->removeOnSerialize === 'Set some value' //correct
$unserialized->setMe === NULL // wrong, it should be 9999
```

As you see after deserialization 'setMe' property is empty.
However 'default' and 'removeOnSerialize' has been passed through.

Any ideas ?

Regards,

Comment: A few issues here: `return serialize($this);` you're serializing the whole class by doing this. `$unserialized = unserialize();` needs to be passed a parameter to unserialize. Look [here](http://php.net/unserialize) on how it works.

Comment: Check your method name. You have `unserialzie` and there should be probably `unserialize`.  Your code is not working after copy/paste - follow the errors and warnings - they will guide you.

Answer (score 2):

As it was already mentioned in comment section you shouldn't return anything from `unserialize` method. It has to set values of the object.
You might also get stack overflow by calling `serialize` on the instance of the same class from `serialize` method.
I guess you can do it like this:

```
class Foo implements \Serializable
{
    public $default = 10;
    public $setMe;
    public $removeOnSerialize = 'blah';

    public function serialize()
    {
        unset($this->removeOnSerialze);
        return serialize($this->getData());
    }

    public function unserialize($serialized)
    {
        foreach (unserialize($serialized) as $key => $value) {
            $this->$key = $value;
        }
        $this->removeOnSerialize = 'Set some value';
    }

    protected function getData()
    {
        return get_object_vars($this);
    }
}
```

Comment: I did it in my first attempt, I lost some properties in inherited objects so I thought it might be better to serialize whole object.

Answer (score 0):

With custom serialization, it becomes your responsibility to provide what you want to save to `serialize()` and your responsibility to parse the values from `unserialize()`

You could change your `serialize` to:

```
public function serialize(){
    $toSave = ['setMe'=>$this->setMe];
    return serialize($toSave);
}
```

This way, `removeOnSerialize` is not saved. To `unserialize` you could do

```
public function unserialize($data){
    $data = unserialize($data);
    $this->setMe = $data['setMe'];
    $this->removeOnSerialize = 'Set some value';
}
```

[**Live demo**](https://3v4l.org/J8N63)